# react-redux-I18n locale update with I18n.t helper

Tags: reactjs, translation, react-redux

I'm using `react-redux-i18n` and I'm having issue updating the `I18n.t helper`

I have a button calling an action which dispatch the setLocale of `react-redux-i18n` :

```
<FlatButton
        label={languageToDisplay}
        labelStyle={styles.buttonLabel}
        onClick={() => this.props.actions.setLanguage(languageToDisplay)}
        style={styles.button}
      />
```

Which call this function:

```
export default function setLanguage(language: string) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setLocale(language));
  };
}
```

While it does change the `I18n._locale`, it doesn't re-render and translate the text. Anyone got an idea as how to fi it?

I'm using `react-redux-i18n` because I like the `react-native` way to translate which is : `I18n.t(...)`

It's clean and it doesn't force weird component only for the translation such as `<FormationMessage />` or `<Translate />`

If anyone know how to fix it or have another library in the same style of translation as `react-redux-i18n`, please let me know :)

Answer (score 2):

Found a workaround for this problem:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

@connect(state => ({
  i18n: state.i18n, // <= this makes your component rerender on language change
}), dispatch => ({ dispatch }))
class SomeClass extends Component {
    ......
}
```

Tell me if you have a better approach.